# How to print dmesg output to host machine from qemu guest vm

Tags: linux, kernel, kvm, qemu

**Command**
Here is what I am doing

```bash
# Step 1. In host machine
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -enable-kvm -nodefaults -nographic -L /usr/share/qemu \
        -m 8G -smp 4 -boot c \
        -netdev user,hostnet0,hostfwd=tcp::5556-:22 \
        -drive file=ubuntu18.04.qcow2,if=virtio,cache=none \
        -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3\
        -serial pty  

# Step 2. In guest machine
$ sudo vim /etc/default/grub
# Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" as GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=ttyS0"

# Step 3. In host machine
# There should be a printed log showing 
# which pty is being used when the host runs qemu
# Let say, /dev/pts/3
$ sudo cat /dev/pts/3 

# Step 4. Login /dev/pts/3
$ echo "id" > /dev/pts/3
$ echo "password" > /dev/pts/3

# Step 5. Print dmesg in a log file
$ echo dmesg > /dev/pts/3
```

What I want is to get a kernel log from the guest machine. The code above is basically using pty as serial port so I am able to get the log through a certain tty, but the problem is there is a warning for this method.

If I issue the command, `dmesg`, I get this message:

```bash
[ 0.00000] serial8250: too much work for irq4
```

I do not believe that this is a critical warning but it is quite annoying to see, and it seems to me that several logs are ignored.

I'd like to know if there is better way to get a log without any warning from the VM. I feel this warning is not right. The way I fix this is by regularly logging in and redirecting an ugly output of `cat`.

Is there a way to get a log right away without using echo dmesg?

Comment: Use `syslog` to pass (kernel) messages across the network from one machine to the other

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative**

```bsh
# Using a named pipeline
# Step 1. qemu configuration
$ qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -some options like above \
        -serial pipe:/tmp/guest

# Step 2. To get a log
$ mkfifo /tmp/guest.in /tmp/guest.out
$ cat /tmp/guest.out
$ printf "id\n" > /tmp/guest.in
$ printf "pw\n" > /tmp/guest.in
$ printf "cmd\n" > /tmp/guest.in
```

[Link](https://fadeevab.com/how-to-setup-qemu-output-to-console-and-automate-using-shell-script/)

Answer (score 0):

You could add `-serial file:console.log` to `qemu-system` and append `console=ttyS0,115200 ignore_loglevel` to the guest kernel parameters.

With `ignore_loglevel`, all kernel messages are printed to the console (here the serial device) regardless of their log level.